# Shopware 6 - form field for entity extension in administration

Tags: shopware, shopware6

This is a Shopware 6 question. I want to extend the `PromotionEntity` by adding a `max_budget` field and display it as a form field in administration. Currently only `max_redemptions_global` and `max_redemptions_per_customer` fields exist. The `max_budget` field should appear in administration right under `max_redemptions_global` and `max_redemptions_per_customer` fields. `max_budget` would act similar to the other two. If the discount for this promotion from total orders combined reaches the value from max_budget, then the promotion does not work anymore.

So I created an entity extension as following:

```
class PromotionMaxBudgetExtension extends EntityExtension
{
    public function extendFields(FieldCollection $collection): void
    {
        $collection->add(
            new OneToOneAssociationField('maxBudget', 'id', 'promotion_id', PromotionMaxBudgetDefinition::class, false)
        );
    }

    public function getDefinitionClass(): string
    {
        return PromotionDefinition::class;
    }
}
```

Then the definition of the extension:

```
class PromotionMaxBudgetDefinition extends EntityDefinition
{
    public const ENTITY_NAME = 'promotion_max_budget';

    public function getEntityName(): string
    {
        return self::ENTITY_NAME;
    }

    public function getEntityClass(): string
    {
        return PromotionMaxBudgetEntity::class;
    }

    protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection
    {
        return new FieldCollection([
            (new IdField('id', 'id'))->addFlags(new Required(), new PrimaryKey()),
            (new FkField('promotion_id', 'promotionId', PromotionDefinition::class)),
            (new IntField('max_budget', 'maxBudget')),
            (new IntField('left_budget', 'leftBudget')),

            (new OneToOneAssociationField('promotion', 'promotion_id', 'id', PromotionDefinition::class, false))
        ]);
    }
}
```

In order to display the field I had to override the `sw-promotion-v2-detail-base`. So I modified the  `sw-promotion-v2-detail-base.html.twig` like this:

```
{% block sw_promotion_v2_detail_base_general_max_uses_customer %}
{% parent %}

<sw-number-field
        v-model="??????"
        class="sw-promotion-v2-detail-base__field-max-uses-per-customer"
        number-type="int"
        :label="Max budget"
        :placeholder="$tc('sw-promotion-v2.detail.base.general.maxUsesPerCustomerPlaceholder')"
        :disabled="!acl.can('promotion.editor')"
        allow-empty
/>
{% endblock %}
```

**So, my question would be, how would I tell Shopware this field is for the max_budget entity extension, so that it would save the changes I make to it, at `onSave` ?** Seems like even though the entity extension exists, it is not fetched as an association for the promotion (even with autoload true).

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so I saw how this needs to be done to work perfectly.

Firstly I had to override `sw-promotion-v2-detail` component and add this js:

```
Shopware.Component.override('sw-promotion-v2-detail', {
    computed: {
        promotionCriteria() {
            const criteria = this.$super('promotionCriteria');

            criteria.addAssociation('maxBudget');

            return criteria;
        }
    },
});
```

Secondly, in the sw-promotion-v2-detail-base.html.twig the field will look like this:

```
<sw-number-field
        v-if="promotion.extensions.maxBudget"
        v-model="promotion.extensions.maxBudget.maxBudget"
        class="sw-promotion-v2-detail-base__field-max-budget"
        number-type="int"
        :label="$tc('vouchers.maxBudget')"
        :placeholder="$tc('sw-promotion-v2.detail.base.codes.individual.generateModal.labelPrefix')"
        :disabled="!acl.can('promotion.editor')"
        allow-empty
/>
```

Notice the v-model changed to `promotion.extensions`.....

So the answer would be this:
**To add a Shopware 6 form field for an entity extension in admin you have to add the entity association for the extension to the component where the extended entity is fetched (in this case sw-promotion-v2-detail).
After that you can use the extension in twig with `promotion.extensions.extensionName`....**

Comment: Is the data now saved in the `max_budget` field?

Answer (score 0):

I found it really useful.
I had a very similar case.
But I had to use a new table to store the extension data (company rules).
So in my case the solution needed a few tweaks.
Note, I've been working in `src/Bundle` if you use it in plugin change the paths.
So to add an extension to entity (here 'promotion') and store data in new table:

1.) Create a migration to add new table:

```
    <?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Bundle\Checkout\Migration;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Migration\MigrationStep;

class Migration1695812917NPS1938AddPromotionExtensionTable extends MigrationStep
{
    public function getCreationTimestamp(): int
    {
        return 1695812917;
    }

    public function update(Connection $connection): void
    {
        $this
            ->createPromotionExtensionTable($connection)
        ;
    }

    protected function createPromotionExtensionTable(Connection $connection): static
    {
        $connection->executeStatement(
            sql: <<<SQL
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nbb_promotion_extension` (
                    `promotion_id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                    `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                    `updated_at` DATETIME NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                    `voucher_description` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
                    FOREIGN KEY `fk_nbb_promotion_extension_promotion_id` (`promotion_id`) REFERENCES `promotion` (`id`)
                    ON DELETE CASCADE
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
            SQL,
        );

        return $this;
    }

    public function updateDestructive(Connection $connection): void
    {
    }
```

2. Create Entity Extension

```
// src/Bundle/Checkout/Promotion/Extension/PromotionExtensionEntity.php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Bundle\Checkout\Promotion\Extension;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Entity;

class PromotionExtensionEntity extends Entity
{
    protected string $promotionId;
    protected string $voucherDescription;

    public function getVoucherDescription(): string
    {
        return $this->voucherDescription;
    }

    public function setVoucherDescription(string $voucherDescription): void
    {
        $this->voucherDescription = $voucherDescription;
    }

    public function getPromotionId(): string
    {
        return $this->promotionId;
    }

    public function setPromotionId(string $promotionId): void
    {
        $this->promotionId = $promotionId;
    }
}
```

3. Create Entity Extension Definition:

```
// src/Bundle/Checkout/Promotion/Extension/PromotionExtensionDefinition.php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Bundle\Checkout\Promotion\Extension;

use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Promotion\PromotionDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\FkField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\PrimaryKey;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\Required;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\OneToOneAssociationField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\StringField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\FieldCollection;

class PromotionExtensionDefinition extends EntityDefinition
{
    public const ENTITY_NAME = 'nbb_promotion_extension';

    public function getEntityName(): string
    {
        return static::ENTITY_NAME;
    }

    public function getEntityClass(): string
    {
        return PromotionExtensionEntity::class;
    }

    protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection
    {
        return new FieldCollection([
            (new FkField('promotion_id', 'promotionId', PromotionDefinition::class))
                ->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),
            new StringField('voucher_description', 'voucherDescription'),
            new OneToOneAssociationField('promotion', 'promotion_id', 'id', PromotionDefinition::class, false),
        ]);
    }
}
```

4.) Create Association (between new table and promotion)

```
// src/Bundle/Checkout/Promotion/Extension/PromotionExtensionAssociation.php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Bundle\Checkout\Promotion\Extension;

use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Promotion\PromotionDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityExtension;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\OneToOneAssociationField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\FieldCollection;

class PromotionExtensionAssociation extends EntityExtension
{
    public function extendFields(FieldCollection $collection): void
    {
        $collection->add(
            new OneToOneAssociationField(
                PromotionExtensionDefinition::ENTITY_NAME,
                'id',
                'promotion_id',
                PromotionExtensionDefinition::class,
                false
            )
        );
    }

    public function getDefinitionClass(): string
    {
        return PromotionDefinition::class;
    }
}
```

This part was rather easy.
Now I needed to find out more to use it in admin.

So as in example above:

5. Add association of created extension to promotion entity

```
// src/Bundle/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-promotion-v2/page/sw-promotion-v2-detail/index.js

Shopware.Component.override('sw-promotion-v2-detail', {
    computed: {
        promotionCriteria() {
            const criteria = this.$super('promotionCriteria');
            criteria.addAssociation('nbb_promotion_extension');

            return criteria;
        }
    },
});
```

That was enough to display already exisitin extension table enntries (so If you've added manually some entries it worked).
But there was still problem with creating new entry.
I had to create extension repository myself if it didn't exist.
So last step was to add this in your module:

```
// src/Bundle/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-promotion-v2/view/sw-promotion-v2-detail-base/index.js

import template from './sw-promotion-v2-detail-base.html.twig';

Shopware.Component.override('sw-promotion-v2-detail-base', {
    template,

    inject: ['repositoryFactory'],

    computed: {
        promotionExtensionRepository() {
            return this.repositoryFactory.create('nbb_promotion_extension');
        },
    },

    created() {
        if (!this.promotion.extensions.nbb_promotion_extension) {
            this.promotion.extensions.nbb_promotion_extension = this.promotionExtensionRepository.create(Shopware.Context.api);
        } else {
            this.nbb_promotion_extension = this.promotion.extensions.nbb_promotion_extension;
            this.voucherDescription = this.promotion.extensions.nbb_promotion_extension.voucher_description;
        }
    },
});
```

Now there are no errors when you create a new Promotion.